# Azure web deploy/publish keeps getting stuck

Tags: azure, web-deployment, webdeploy

every time I try to publish my web app to azure it gets stuck, how can I determine what the problem is? logs etc, I cant see anything but the output but thats not enough to diagnose the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So the way I got around this issue was to set the visual studio parallel build settings to 1.

this would force visual studio to build each individual project one after the other, and this way you would be able to diagnose if there is something going wrong during the build stage or not.

fortunately for me nothing was wrong with the build stage and my project got published fine.

Comment: To change the setting in Visual Studio go to Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run

Answer (score 1):

Same thing I have faced many times, process stuck while publishing Web app.This is related to network speed. May be at that time your network speed is slow. Please make sure while your will going to publish your network speed should be high.
This is work for me.